# Show that a space is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

How to show the following-

If $X$ is a topological space and for every $x, y \in X$ there exists a connected subset $C \subseteq X$ with $x, y \in C$, then is $X$ connected?

I have a feeling that it is but can't really show why. Could someone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Assume that $X$ is not connected. What does there exist then?

Comment: No. Before you start you should be familiar with what it means that a top. space is connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supose not, then there are two open *non-empty* sets $\;A,B\subset X\;$ with both $\;A\cup B=X\;,\;\;A\cap B=\emptyset\;$.

But now take elements $\;a\in A\,,\,\,b\in B\;$ and use the given data: there exists a connected $\;C\subset X\;$ with $\;a,b\in C\;$ . Deduce now your contradiction.

Comment: how do you know that A and B are connected?

Comment: @verticese You don't know that $A$ and $B$ are connected, but consider the set $C$ under the subspace topology. What can you say about $C$ given what you know about $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @verticese Thank you. That was a typo (in fact, an unnoticed "copy and past"). Of course we don't require $\;A,B\;$ connected.